# How to convert app.config file to XML?

Tags: c#, parsing, app-config, converters

I use this to get the content from the app.config file:

```
string content = File.ReadAllLines(
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile)
```

How can I convert `app.config` file into XML after parsing config this way? What are the best practices for parsing?

Comment: the best practice for parse app.config is not to parse at all...

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are doing something really special with it, you should not directly read the `app.config` file, but use [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to read from it.
If you really want to read it as XML, use [XmlDocumen.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/875kz807.aspx) function, but plaease keep in mind that parsing config as an XML file is an unintended way of use.

Comment: document.Save(), although I not recommend altering your .config like that.